# Shopify: Change metafields for store

Tags: shopify, liquid

My problem is that when you login on my store - you (not necessarily registered) could add your e-mail and other information.
In this topic: 
https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/t/allowing-a-customer-to-edit-their-profile-and-metadata-186665

I see that there is a possibility to change the metafields of the customer.

But I need to change the metafields of the store. 
Does someone know where to find a list of requests or is there any options to change Metafields?

Comment: metafields for shop only is for api using : https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/shop#shop-metafields

Comment: @miglio it's just a description of the object - but I need to change metafields on client side - I think it should be possible because in the case of the customer metafields it is possible

Comment: @Maria you can't allow any customer / visitor to alter your store metafields unless you write an app which uses the Shopify API

Answer (score 1):

If you, as somebody with admin access to the store, needs to manually set or modify metafields on your store and either don't want to (or cannot) use a custom app to do so:

1. Get the (free) ShopifyFD extension for your browser ([Link to the extension on the Chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopifyfd-dashboard-tool/lffljkleilfpjlmcdnoaghhcbnemelge?hl=en-US))
2. Log in to your store and go to the 'Settings' (gear icon)
3. Click ShopifyFD's green '+' icon in your browser to load the extension on the page. You should now see your store metafields appear
4. You can now add metafields by filling in the boxes, or select existing metafields to manually edit their values.

Note: Metafields that are set by any of the apps that your are using should generally not be edited manually  - changing an auto-generated field could really confuse the app that relies on it!